# I am trying to create an object using reduce method but not getting the output

Tags: javascript

```js
let opt = {
    '0_first': "Hello0",
    '0_Second': "hi1",
    '1_first': "Hello1",
    '1_Second': "h2",
    '2_first': "Hello2",
    '3_first': "hello",
    '0_third' : "Third"
};

let fieldValuesuu = ['Field_1', 'Field_2', 'Field_3'];

function getOptionsData(options) {
    Object.entries(options).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
        const option = key.split('_')[1];
        let arr = [];
        if (key.includes(fieldValuesuu[key])) {
            arr.push(value)
            obje[fieldValuesuu[key]] = arr;
        }
    },{});
}

console.log('reduceValue', getOptionsData(opt));
```

Expected output:

```
   {
     Field_1 : [Hello0, Hello1, Hello2, hello];
     Field_2 : [hi1, h2];
     Field_3 : [Third]

   }
```

I am trying to create an object using reduce. I have an array and an object to get the expected output I have to take keys of output Object from an array and first, second and third from opt I have to assign values to output object.

Comment: What is `obje`? Shouldn't that be `acc`? You need to return `acc` from the function.

Comment: It looks like you just forgot to *return* anything from your function?  (Among other potential problems I imagine...)

Comment: `fieldValuesuu[key]` makes no sense. `fieldValuesuu` is an array, `key` is a string, not an array index.

Comment: You never use `option` anywhere.

Comment: I can't figure out how the desired output is related to the inputs.

Comment: Can you explain `if (key.includes(fieldValuesuu[key])) {`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot map to new keys in the expected output using the array you have defined `['Field_1', 'Field_2', 'Field_3']`. You need to have a mapping of data keys to new keys like:

```
let mapping = { first: "Field_1", Second: "Field_2", third: "Field_3" };
```

Try like this:

```js
let opt = {
  "0_first": "Hello0",
  "0_Second": "hi1",
  "1_first": "Hello1",
  "1_Second": "h2",
  "2_first": "Hello2",
  "3_first": "hello",
  "0_third": "Third",
};

let mapping = { first: "Field_1", Second: "Field_2", third: "Field_3" };

const output = Object.entries(opt).reduce((prev, [key, value]) => {
  const [index, dataName] = key.split("_");
  const newKey = mapping[dataName];
  if (!prev[newKey]) {
    prev[newKey] = [];
  }
  prev[newKey].push(value);
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar, updated with explanation